# 'GibHub App' authentication with a maven style Jenkins build cannot perform maven release due to Auth failure

Tags: git, maven, github, jenkins

I am trying to use 'GibHub App' authentication with a maven style Jenkins build.

The initial check out works fine, but when I use the **maven release:prepare release:perform** feature, the build fails because maven cannot push back to Github to create a release tag.

The following message appears in the log

```
The git-push command failed.
Command output:
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by us using docker containers that only lasted the life of the build.

We solved this by adding a 'Prepare environment for the run' section with the following script content

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

So when maven needed to push a tag to git, it could used the stored credentials